# Не могу понять Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Можете на простом языке объяснить для чего sessionFactory, CriteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery, Root?

```
public List<Cities> getCitiesByCountry(Long id) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Cities> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Cities.class);
    Root root = query.from(Cities.class);
    Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("countries").get("id"), id);
    List<Cities> list = session.createQuery(query.where(predicate)).getResultList();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Имена всех классов и переменных говорящие: sessionFactory для открытия сессии с СУБД, criteriaBuilder для построения критериев запроса, CriteriaQuery - сам запрос к СУБД, Root - корневой элемент запроса.

Comment: @Hivemaster оформите комментарий в виде ответа

Comment: @Barmaley готово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имена всех классов и переменных говорящие: `SessionFactory` для открытия сессии с СУБД, `CriteriaBuilder` для построения критериев запроса, `CriteriaQuery` - сам запрос к СУБД, `Root` - корневой элемент запроса.

Comment: спасибо большое)